# Android OBJ to VBO loader, Garbage Collection loop, how to improve?

Tags: android, opengl-es, garbage-collection, vbo, wavefront

I've just recently gotten an OBJ loader and viewing Android application working correctly with vertices, normals and texture coordinates, but in order to keep track of these data values correctly, I ended up with a lot of individual objects being created. One thing that I read online was that long Strings or large Arrays/ArrayLists of Strings take up an outrageous amount of memory. I attempted to get rid of the two separate methods, one that parses the file into an ArrayList of Strings and one that reads through that ArrayList, by combining the two while removing the storage of the lines in the file into a large ArrayList. I replaced my code so that it was instead interpreting the file as it read through it, but this didn't reduce the model load time either. The test model I am using is the Suzanne monkey head, subdivided once in Blender and exported as an OBJ, with roughly 2000 vertices. I am not sure what else to do to fend off the garbage collector. Another note, this is built for Android 2.2, so I do not have the option of specifying a larger heap size as in Android 3.0 and beyond. Any pointers that can be given are greatly appreciated, as I want to make this loader load as quickly as possible, but I am not entirely sure how to do that.

Here is the source thus far:

```
public class OBJToolkit {
    private static ArrayList<String> parseOBJ(String modelLocation) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(modelLocation)));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(reader.ready())
        {
            lines.add(reader.readLine());
        }
        reader.close();
        reader = null;
        return lines;
    }

    public static Mesh loadOBJ(String modelLocation) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Location searched for model: " + modelLocation);

        ArrayList<Vector3f> allVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> allTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> allNormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();

        ArrayList<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        ArrayList<String> lines = parseOBJ(modelLocation);

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to read the contents of the model");
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            if (line == null)
                break;

            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                allVertices.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vt "))
            {
                allTextureCoords.add(new Vector2f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]),Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                allNormals.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                //Log.d("OBJToolkit", line);
                Face f = new Face();
                String[] faceVertexArray = line.split(" ");

                for (int index = 1; index < faceVertexArray.length; index++)
                {
                    String[] valueArray = faceVertexArray[index].split("/");

                    if (allTextureCoords.size() > 0)
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), allTextureCoords.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[1]) - 1)));
                    else
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), new Vector2f(0, 0)));
                }
                faces.add(f);
            }
        }

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of vertices: " + allVertices.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of normals: " + allNormals.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of texture coords: " + allTextureCoords.size());

        lines = null;
        allVertices = null;
        allNormals = null;
        allTextureCoords = null;

        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBOVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> VBOTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBONormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Integer> VBOIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to reorganize each point of data");
        int counter = 0;
        for (Face f : faces)
        {
            for (Vertex v : f.vertices)
            {
                VBOVertices.add(v.position);
                VBONormals.add(v.normal);
                VBOTextureCoords.add(v.textureCoord);
                VBOIndices.add(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        faces = null;

        mesh.createBuffers(vector3fListToFloatArray(VBOVertices), integerListToShortArray(VBOIndices), null, vector2fListToFloatArray(VBOTextureCoords), vector3fListToFloatArray(VBONormals));

        VBOVertices = null;
        VBONormals = null;
        VBOTextureCoords = null;
        VBOIndices = null;
        return mesh;
    }

    public static void printFloatArrayList(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static String floatArrayToString(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static String vector3fArrayToString(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            strToPrint += v.x + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.y + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.z + ", ";
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static void printStringArray(String[] list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (String s : list)
        {
            strToPrint += s + ",";
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static void printIntegerArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static float[] floatListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Float");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Float i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = i.floatValue();
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static short[] integerListToShortArray(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Integer");
        short[] returnArray = new short[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = (short)i;
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector3fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector3f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 3];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.z;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector2fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector2f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector2f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 2];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector2f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

I've thought about replacing the use of the Vector3f and Vector2f classes that I made and using arrays instead, but I'm not sure whether this would actually decrease the memory usage or not, since the array object has all of that extra functionality that I don't need.

I've also tried to set things that I no longer need equal to null in the hopes that the GC would automatically get rid of them, leaving more memory in the heap, but it doesn't seem to help at all.

The OBJToolkit class is the main class here, but just in case I will include the other associated classes below:

Mesh:

```
public class Mesh { 
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indicesBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer normalsBuffer;
    private int numOfIndices = -1;
    private float[] rgba = new float[] {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
    private int mTextureId = -1;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mShouldLoadTexture = false;

    public float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, rx = 0, ry = 0, rz = 0;

    public Mesh() {

    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        //Log.d("Mesh", "About to render mesh");
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsBuffer);
        gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
        if (colorBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        }

        if (mShouldLoadTexture)
        {
            loadGLTexture(gl);
            mShouldLoadTexture = false;
        }

        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        }

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public void setTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void createBuffers(float[] vertices, short[] indices, float[] colors, float[] textureCoords, float[] normals)
    {
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Vertices: " + floatArrayToString(vertices));
        setVertices(vertices);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Indices: " + shortArrayToString(indices));
        setIndices(indices);
        if (colors != null)
            setColors(colors);
        if (textureCoords != null)
            setTextureCoordinates(textureCoords);
        if (normals != null)
            setNormals(normals);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Texture Coors: " + floatArrayToString(textureCoords));
    }

    public String floatArrayToString(float[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += ", " + array[i];
        }
        if (returnString.length() > 2)
            return returnString.substring(2);
        else
            return returnString;
    }

    public String shortArrayToString(short[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += ", " + array[i];
        }
        if (returnString.length() > 2)
            return returnString.substring(2);
        else
            return returnString;
    }

    protected void setVertices(float[] vertices)
    {
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setIndices(short[] indices)
    {
        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indicesBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indicesBuffer.put(indices);
        indicesBuffer.position(0);
        numOfIndices = indices.length;
    }

    protected void setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
    {
        rgba[0] = red;
        rgba[1] = green;
        rgba[2] = blue;
        rgba[3] = alpha;
    }

    protected void setColors(float[] colors)
    {
        ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setTextureCoordinates(float[] textureCoords)
    {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTextureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
        mTextureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setNormals(float[] normals)
    {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(normals.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        normalsBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        normalsBuffer.put(normals);
        normalsBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void loadBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        mShouldLoadTexture = true;
    }

    private void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl)
    {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        mTextureId = textures[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmap, 0);
    }
}
```

Face:

```
public class Face {
    ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    public Face()
    {

    }

    public void addVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        vertices.add(vertex);
    }
}
```

Vertex:

```
public class Vertex {
    public Vector3f position, normal;
    public Vector2f textureCoord;

    public Vertex(Vector3f pos, Vector3f norm, Vector2f textCoord)
    {
        position = pos;
        normal = norm;
        textureCoord = textCoord;
    }
}
```

Vector3f:

```
public class Vector3f {
    public float x, y, z;

    public Vector3f()
    {
        setTo(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        setTo(x, y, z);
    }

    public void setTo(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public float lengthSquared()
    {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    }

    public float length()
    {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(lengthSquared());
    }

    public Vector3f add(Vector3f v)
    {
        return new Vector3f(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
    }

    public Vector3f addAndSet(Vector3f v)
    {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        z += v.z;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3f crossProduct(Vector3f v)
    {
        return new Vector3f(y * v.z - z * v.y,
                z * v.x - x * z,
                x * v.y - y * v.x
                );
    }

    public Vector3f negate()
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
        z *= -1;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3f normalize()
    {
        float l = length();

        return new Vector3f(x / l, y / l, z / l);
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector3f v)
    {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }

    public float angleBetween(Vector3f v)
    {
        float dls = dotProduct(v) / (length() * v.length());
        if (dls < -1f)
            dls = -1f;
        else if (dls > 1.0f)
            dls = 1.0f;
        return (float)Math.acos(dls);
    }

    public Vector3f scale(float scale)
    {
        return new Vector3f(x * scale, y * scale, z * scale);
    }

    public Vector3f scaleAndSet(float scale)
    {
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
        z *= scale;
        return this;
    }


}
```

Vector2f:

```
public class Vector2f {
    public float x, y;

    public Vector2f()
    {
        setTo(0, 0);
    }

    public Vector2f(float x, float y)
    {
        setTo(x, y);
    }

    public void setTo(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float lengthSquared()
    {
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    public float length()
    {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(lengthSquared());
    }

    public Vector2f add(float x, float y)
    {
        return new Vector2f(this.x + x, this.y + y);
    }

    public Vector2f addAndSet(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector2f negate()
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector2f normalize()
    {
        float l = length();
        return new Vector2f(x / l, y / l);
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector2f v)
    {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y;
    }

    public float angleBetween(Vector2f v)
    {
        float dls = dotProduct(v) / (length() * v.length());
        if (dls < -1f)
            dls = -1f;
        else if (dls > 1.0f)
            dls = 1.0f;
        return (float)Math.acos(dls);
    }

    public Vector2f scale(float scale)
    {
        return new Vector2f(x * scale, y * scale);
    }

    public Vector2f scaleAndSet(float scale)
    {
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
        return this;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        MyGLSurfaceView view = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        OpenGLRenderer renderer = new OpenGLRenderer();
        view.renderer = renderer;
        //renderer.plane.loadBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        view.setRenderer(renderer);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener
{
    OpenGLRenderer renderer;
    GestureDetector detector;

    float lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

    float onDown = 0, onUp = 0;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        detector = new GestureDetector(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
    {
        detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "X: " + me.getX());
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Y: " + me.getY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onTouch event");
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "X: " + me.getX());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Y: " + me.getY());
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            lastY = me.getY();
        }
        else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            renderer.moveMesh(me.getY() - lastY);
        }
        /*
        if (lastX == 0)
        {
            lastX = me.getX();
        }
        if (lastY == 0)
        {
            lastY = me.getY();
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", String.valueOf((me.getY() - lastY) * 0.1f));
        renderer.moveMesh(me.getY() - lastY);
        */
        lastY = me.getY();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onDown Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onFling Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onLongPress Event");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onScroll Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onShowPress Event");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onSIngleTapUp Event");
        return false;
    }

}
```

OpenGLRenderer:

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer
{
    //SmoothColoredSquare smoothSquare = new SmoothColoredSquare();
    //Cube cube = new Cube(1, 1, 1);
    public Mesh plane;

    public float meshMoveSpeed = .05f, planePosition = 0f;

    float zNear = 0.01f, zFar = 1000.0f, fieldOfView = 45.0f, size;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "About to attempt to load model");
        try {
            plane = OBJToolkit.loadOBJ(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/testModel.obj");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("FNF", "testModel.obj not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("IOE", "testModel.obj not found IOE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //.z = -7.7f;
        //plane.rx = -10;
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);
        float ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        float diffuseColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        float lightPosition[] = {-2f, 5f, -2f, 1f};
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, ambientColor, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseColor, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION, lightPosition, 0);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        gl.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        //Reset viewport
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        //Select projection matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        size = (float) (zNear * Math.tan((fieldOfView / 180.0f) * Math.PI) / 2.0f);
        gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (width / height), size / (width / height), zNear, zFar);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        //Reset projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        //Calculate aspect ratio of window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, -5f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        //Select modelview matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        //Reset modelview matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Clear the screen before drawing
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //plane.ry += 2f;
        //plane.rz += 2f;

        plane.x += meshMoveSpeed;
        plane.z = planePosition;
        if (plane.x > 3f)
        {
            meshMoveSpeed *= -1;
        }
        else if(plane.x < -3f)
        {
            meshMoveSpeed *= -1;
        }

        //Reset the current position held by OpenGL, otherwise the
        //camera will be pushed farther and farther back every frame
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        //Move the camera backwards in order to actually see the face
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0f, -15f);

        plane.draw(gl);
    }

    public void moveMesh(float distance)
    {
        planePosition += distance * 0.05f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings...So many strings that the GC got stuck attempting to clear them all. Part of the problem lies in the reading of the file into a large ArrayList of Strings, but the biggest issue was in the debug calls in the Mesh class. It looped through every object in the passed in Array and added it to a String via += along with a comma separator. That resulted in thousands of Strings that weren't being used sitting in memory. Needless to say, I've rewritten some of the application and removed the debug calls, as they aren't needed now anyways, but I suppose I'll rewrite them to use the StringBuilder at some point as well. The only code I really changed was in the OBJToolkit class, so here it is:

```
public class OBJToolkit {

    public static String getStringFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception
    {
        File fl = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
        String returnString = convertStreamToString(fin);
        fin.close();
        return returnString;
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static Mesh loadOBJ(String modelLocation) throws Exception
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Location searched for model: " + modelLocation);

        ArrayList<Vector3f> allVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> allTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> allNormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();

        ArrayList<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        String lines = getStringFromFile(modelLocation);

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to read the contents of the model");
        String[] individualLines = lines.split("\\n");

        int numberOfLines = individualLines.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            String line = individualLines[i];
            if (line == null)
                break;

            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                allVertices.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vt "))
            {
                allTextureCoords.add(new Vector2f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]),Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                allNormals.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                //Log.d("OBJToolkit", line);
                Face f = new Face();
                String[] faceVertexArray = line.split(" ");

                for (int index = 1; index < faceVertexArray.length; index++)
                {
                    String[] valueArray = faceVertexArray[index].split("/");

                    if (allTextureCoords.size() > 0)
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), allTextureCoords.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[1]) - 1)));
                    else
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), new Vector2f(0, 0)));
                }
                faces.add(f);
            }
        }

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of vertices: " + allVertices.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of normals: " + allNormals.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of texture coords: " + allTextureCoords.size());

        lines = null;
        allVertices = null;
        allNormals = null;
        allTextureCoords = null;

        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBOVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> VBOTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBONormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Integer> VBOIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to reorganize each point of data");
        int counter = 0;
        for (Face f : faces)
        {
            for (Vertex v : f.vertices)
            {
                VBOVertices.add(v.position);
                VBONormals.add(v.normal);
                VBOTextureCoords.add(v.textureCoord);
                VBOIndices.add(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        faces = null;

        mesh.createBuffers(vector3fListToFloatArray(VBOVertices), integerListToShortArray(VBOIndices), null, vector2fListToFloatArray(VBOTextureCoords), vector3fListToFloatArray(VBONormals));

        VBOVertices = null;
        VBONormals = null;
        VBOTextureCoords = null;
        VBOIndices = null;
        return mesh;
    }

    public static void printFloatArrayList(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static String floatArrayToString(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static String vector3fArrayToString(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            strToPrint += v.x + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.y + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.z + ", ";
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static void printStringArray(String[] list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (String s : list)
        {
            strToPrint += s + ",";
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static void printIntegerArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static float[] floatListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Float");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Float i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = i.floatValue();
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static short[] integerListToShortArray(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Integer");
        short[] returnArray = new short[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = (short)i;
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector3fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector3f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 3];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.z;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector2fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector2f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector2f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 2];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector2f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone in some way.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at this, so I can't really speak for its efficiency, but i believe the code presented here works. The Mesh class is documented in the question itself. The code in the answer shows how to load data from an OBJ file into a Mesh object